# SVN Merge Issue in Intellij IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am doing a SVN merge in Intellij. Though I have resolved all conflict files that were in the pop up window that come after selecting 'merge all'. But still there are red colored files. Though, these files have no difference, nor are one of the above conflict files.

I would like to add there is one extra option coming on selecting those files - 'Mark Tree Conflict Resolved'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  You do want to utilize the option that the merge conflict has been resolved after you perform the merge.  Keep in mind when a conflict occurs in SVN it generates a .mine file, rOLDREV and .rNEWREV files.

> After a merge execute the → Resolved and commit your modifications to the repository. Please note that the Resolve command does not really resolve the conflict. It just removes the filename.ext.mine and filename.ext.r* files, to allow you to commit your changes.

Answer (score 1):

IDE helps you to resolve text conflicts with a merge tool.
Since it is a Tree conflict, probably there were more differences (e.g. folders structure, properties, etc.) that were not resolved automatically.

To finish merge you need to make sure everything you wanted is merged, mark them as resolved and commit the merge.